# Lazy Loading : How to integrate SDWebImage with current project?

Tags: iphone, lazy-loading, sdwebimage

I am trying to implement lazy loading in my app. And I got `SDWebImage` static library.

Now I am not getting any idea how do I integrate it in my current project.
What are the steps to start work?

Any tutorials to fulfill my task will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

import this file in your .h

```
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"

and use following method,

[UIImageViewName setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.jpg"]];
```

Comment: I want to show an activity indicator while the image is getting downloaded, So the aim is to start animation of activity indicator once the image starts download and stop animation once download is complete,So how can i do with SDWebImage?